# Ipython notebook widgets not showing values

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

For some reason my Ipython notebook widgets stopped working after I upgraded to pandas 0.16 (seems unrelated but thought I'd mention it). I'd love to post a screenshot but StackOverflow won't let me because I'm new and don't have enough "reputation" apparently. I'm trying this basic code, and as you can see from the screenshot the dropdown menu, nor the radio button values populate the widgets. I'm running the notebook in Python 2 mode.  Is this a known issue?!

```
from IPython.html.widgets import interact, interactive, fixed
from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.display import clear_output, display, HTML

temp_w = widgets.Dropdown(values={'1':1, '2':2})
display(temp_w)

mysecondwidget = widgets.RadioButtons(values=["Item A", "Item B", "Item C"])
display(mysecondwidget)
```

Comment: You can upload the screenshot to a third party image hoster and provide the link here. Users with sufficient reputation can then add the image to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

closing this. when I used the [newer] 'options=' parameter instead of values it started working again. possibly when i upgraded pandas, under the hood, it upgraded other dependencies i suppose which require the widget objects to only accept the newer options param